# Create Print Layout issue in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Create Print Layout in my QGIS doesn't show an option to write a name for the project.

How to fix this issue? See the snapshot below:

[image]

Comment: Please provide details on your workflow and QGIS version.

Comment: Share your "about" dialog in the "Help" menu.